# How to append HTML tags in empty document with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, element

I have a function that returns a list of HTML elements to be added to another tag. This function is meant to be called as follow:

```
$('#somewhere').append(getElements())
```

To test the feasibility I wrote this:

```
var el = $() 

for (u in ['foo', 'bar']) {
    el.append($('<li>').addClass(u).text(u + 'Text'))
}

$('<ul>').append(el).html()
```

Eventually I get nothing into `<ul>`. Why? Where is my mistake? I suspect the `$()` to not work as wanted because if I do `var el = $('<div>')` instead, then it works.

**Note**

I could have used:

```
getElementsInto('#somewhere')
```

But I would prefer:

```
$('#somewhere').append(getElements())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) appends the given elements to every element in the jQuery set you call it on. `$()` is an empty jQuery set, so `append` on it is a no-op. There are no elements to append to. (Also note that you're using the [wrong style of loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) to loop through an array; in your loop, `u` will be `"0"` and then `"1"`.) Also, calling `.html()` without using the return value is a no-op.

[`add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) would create a new jQuery object with the additions:

```js
var elements = $();

['foo', 'bar'].forEach(function(u) {
    elements = elements.add($('<li>').addClass(u).text(u + 'Text'));
});

var ul = $('<ul>').append(elements);
// then append `ul` somewhere...
ul.appendTo(document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

...but I think I'd build up the elements in an array. In your case, since your starting point is an array, you can use `map`:

```js
var elements = ['foo', 'bar'].map(function(u) {
  return $('<li>').addClass(u).text(u + 'Text');
});

var ul = $('<ul>').append(elements);
// then append `ul` somewhere...
ul.appendTo(document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are great at explanation.